# why does Apple push server think I am using SSLv3 when I specify TLS? (apple push switch to tls)

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I apologize in advance, but I am asking the same question as here: [How to send iOS Push Notifications using TLS and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577852/how-to-send-ios-push-notifications-using-tls-and-php) because the problem remains unresolved. Here is the Ray Wenderlich tutorial php code I am using to try to send a push notification, as modified per SO post's recommendations:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '325bcd9d15ab8b5f8ff6f4f3d5ab3a5254f1ce775d48828476f4aaff4c5c3d3f';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I also downloaded the entrust_2048_ca.cer file and ensured that it shows up on the System tab of my keychain access. When I run this php file, I still get the following errors, which is the same set of errors I got before making changes to reflect use of tls:

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /Users/aileenann/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 22

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/aileenann/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 22

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Users/aileenann/Desktop/SimplePush/simplepush.php on line 22
Failed to connect: 0
```

What else needs to be changed? Why does the tls apple server still think I am trying to use SSL3 when I have specified tls in the URL?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: This error seems to be mentioned in contexts where the cert is expired (Even if TLS is used). Are you sure it's loaded correctly and that the path works? Also, are the permissions correct?

Comment: @Rick Thank you for the comment. I just downloaded/generated the certificates today while following the tutorial. Also manually testing access from the command line with this command works: openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem I just created the ck.pem by cat-ing together these two .pem files like so:  cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem (also as directed in the tutorial). So I don't think the keys are wrong or the certificate expired.

Comment: It's never the easy answers but it was worth a try ;) Are you sure it's correct in PHP as well? I'm not that familiar with PHP but is there a way to make sure that it has found the certificate and read it correctly?

Comment: @Rick This is my first time on this, so I suppose you're right this is what I should figure out next. The code is copied from a popular tutorial, but something could be going wrong on my end. I'll look into this.